# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Error (CORS) Angular 10

Tags: angular, cors, http-headers

I was made Web Application Using Angular 10 (Front-end) and Node.js(Backend). But when I send requests by adding Headers it was not working. (It was worked when Turn off CORS and send a request on Chrome)
I was found lack some similar answers on StackOverflow but unfortunately, those are not worked for me :|

I sent a request as follows,

```
getAllSubmissions() {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem('auth-token');
    let path = this.globe.base_path + 'get-submissions';
    this.http.get<any>(path, {headers:{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', 'auth-token':token}}).toPromise().then(data => {
      this.allsubmissoinsFiltered = data.filter(sub => sub.status != 'active')
      this.allSubmissionsCount = this.allsubmissoinsFiltered.length;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

as well as, also i was try following code,

```
getAllSubmissions() {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem('auth-token');
    var header = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('auth-token', token) }
    let path = this.globe.base_path + 'get-submissions';
    this.http.get<any>(path, header).toPromise().then(data => {
      this.allsubmissoinsFiltered = data.filter(sub => sub.status != 'active')
      this.allSubmissionsCount = this.allsubmissoinsFiltered.length;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

both types are not working properly. It was displayed error as follows,
[image: Console displayed Error]

[image: On Network]

[image]

How can I fix this issue? Hopefully waiting for your valuable response!

Comment: There ARE questions and answers like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517800/cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the-remot/64517968#64517968

Comment: @BojanKogoj It also not working :(

Comment: I was fixed that issue. It was happened due to the Custom Header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Issue cased due to a custom header set using [Angular HTTPClient](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/),
I was change the code as follows,

```
getAllSubmissions() {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem('auth-token');
    var header = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', token) }
    let path = this.globe.base_path + 'get-submissions';
    this.http.get<any>(path, header).toPromise().then(data => {
      this.allsubmissoinsFiltered = data.filter(sub => sub.status != 'active')
      this.allSubmissionsCount = this.allsubmissoinsFiltered.length;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

Note: I also changed the backend header name to " Authorization"

Now it's working properly.