# "CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present ", but it is present

Tags: php, angular, header, cors

I'm trying to log in or register in my Angular app, but whenever I access to the php file which does the HTTP calls to the DB regarding users (authentication.php), I get three errors:

1. `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/authentication.php?command=login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`
2. `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://localhost/authentication.php","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost/authentication.php: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}`
3. `GET http://localhost/authentication.php?command=login net::ERR_FAILED`

(The last one says GET for login, POST for register)

In `authentication.php` I have the following code regarding headers:

```
require "openDB.php";
include "validators/usuarioValidator.php";
```

In `openDB.php`:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE, POST, GET');
```

In `validators/usuarioValidator.php`:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE, POST, GET');
```

I've tried writing those headers in `authentication.php`, adding OPTIONS to Allow-Methods and allow all origins with *, but I still get the same three errors.

My `user.service.ts` has the following code regarding these operations:

```
register(user : any, key : string) : Promise<any>{
    let parametros = new HttpParams().set("command", "register");

    user.verif = key;

    return this.http.post(this.url, user, {params: parametros}).toPromise();
  }
```

(I'm just pasting register because login is a bit weirdly done and the problem here seems to be with `authentication.php`, no matter what operation it makes)

I've also tried adding `withCredentials: true` and `responseType: "blob"` to params since I'm not receiving a json in the TS, but still nothing.

Comment: Refer to the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66173974/cross-origin-resource-sharing-error-cors-angular-10  it also will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not setting Headers properly in your HTTP Request body, try the following code,

```
register(user : any, key : string) : Promise<any>{
    let parametros = new HttpParams().set("command", "register");

    user.verif = key;

    return this.http.post(this.url, user, {Headers: parametros}).toPromise();
  }
```

Also, if you use the **HTTPClient** package to make requests then it's a bit hard to set **custom headers**.
If you can prevent some issues (like **CORS** Access-Control Errors) by using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or a similar package

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm guessing because you forgot to change HttpParams for HttpHeaders. However, I've been using params like this in a few other files and they work just fine, along with the headers in the .php file.